# on option click checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have these set, now I have item2, item3, ect....

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item1" id="item1" value="pack1" style="padding-right:10px">

<select name="amount1" id="amount1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

what I want is an easy script to make checkbox clicked when they pick any value from the options like

```
$( ".amount$i" ).change(function() {

    if ($('#item$i').prop('checked', false))
    {
        $('#item$$i').prop('checked', true);
    }

});
```

Where the `$i` is meaning to check each variable 1 to ∞

Comment: Thanks for the great insight already. I added the $ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems

```
$("#amount$i").change(function () {
    if (!$('#item$$i').is(':checked')) {
        $('#item$$i').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

- `amount1` is an id so need to use id selector like `#amountx`
- Missing `$` in the `if` condition
- You need to use the [getter version](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName) of [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) like `!$('#item$$i').prop('checked')== false` or use the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) with [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xy4kv3qy/)

Note: If you have multiple set of elements in this format, instead of registering separate handlers for each of them try to use a common event handler

Comment: @C-linkNepal don't know what template language is used... so hopefully OP has it right

Comment: Thanks much, I would bump you, but they keep banning my accounts and I can't gain level.

Comment: Well I have multiple items, so I would need unique numbers for each to correspond to the checkbox and option, unless I used label or something......